# study the convergence of sequence $(x_n)^n, x_{n+1}=\frac{5 x_n}{4+x_n}+\frac{1}{100 n}$

Tags: calculus

$$ x_1=\frac{1}{100},$$
$$x_{n+1}=\frac{5 x_n}{4+x_n}+\frac{1}{100 n}$$

Find $$\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n)^n$$

Comment: Is there an off by one error here?  It looks like $x_1$ is undefined (division by $0$).

Comment: I think you should start with $x_1$ ... I mean $x_1=1/100$, ...

Comment: ok, $x_1=1/100$

Comment: How did this get two up votes?

Comment: [Here's a plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uuxyi.png) of the limit up to $n=100$. Not that it's definitive, but it appears to be about $1.0005$

Comment: Show by induction that $0<x_n<1$. Use that to show by induction that $x_n$ is increasing and therefore it has a limit. Taking limits on the recurrence you get that the limit can only be $0$ or $1$. Therefore it is $1$. Now, $x_n^n=(1+(x_n-1))^{1/(x_n-1)\times(n(x_n-1))}$. Therefore, if we find the limit of $n(x_n-1)$ to be $L$ then the limit of $x_n^n$ is $e^L$. To ease my typing call $y_n=n(x_n-1)$.

Comment: From the recurrence we get that $y_{n+1}=\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{4}{4+x_n}y_n+\frac{1}{100}$. Since $x_n$ increases all the way to $1$, we get that $0<\frac{n}{n-1}\frac{4}{4+x_n}<r<1$. Therefore $y_n$ converges. Taking limits in its recurrence we get that $y_n\to\frac{5}{100}$. Therefore, $x_n^n\to e^{5/100}$